# Using Context Manager for Control Flow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if something like this is possible in python (3.2, if that's relevant).

```python
with assign_match('(abc)(def)', 'abcdef') as (a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

Where the behavior is:

- if the regex matches, the regex groups get assigned to `a` and `b`

  - if there's a mismatch there, it'd throw an exception
- if the match is `None`, it would just bypass the context entirely

My goal here is basically an extremely concise way of doing the contextual behavior.

I tried making the following context manager:

```python
import re

class assign_match(object):
    def __init__(self, regex, string):
        self.regex = regex
        self.string = string
    def __enter__(self):
        result = re.match(self.regex, self.string)
        if result is None:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return result.groups()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print(self, type, value, traceback) #testing purposes. not doing anything here.

with assign_match('(abc)(def)', 'abcdef') as (a, b):
    print(a, b) #prints abc def
with assign_match('(abc)g', 'abcdef') as (a, b): #raises ValueError
    print(a, b)
```

It actually works exactly as desired for the case when the regexes match, but, as you can see, it throws the `ValueError` if there's no match. Is there any way I can get it to "jump" to the exit sequence?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! Perhaps explaining it on SO clarified the problem for me. I just use an if statement instead of a with statement.

```
def assign_match(regex, string):
    match = re.match(regex, string)
    if match is None:
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        yield match.groups()

for a in assign_match('(abc)(def)', 'abcdef'):
    print(a)
```

Gives exactly the behavior I'd like. Leaving this here in case other people want to benefit from it. (Mods, if it's not relevant, feel free to delete, etc.)

**EDIT:** Actually, this solution comes with one fairly large flaw. I'm doing this behavior within a for-loop. So this prevents me from doing:

```
for string in lots_of_strings:
    for a in assign_match('(abc)(def)', string):
        do_my_work()
        continue # breaks out of this for loop instead of the parent
    other_work() # behavior i want to skip if the match is successful
```

Because the continue now breaks out of this loop instead of the parent for loop. If anyone has suggestions, I'd love to hear!

**EDIT2**: Alright, figured it out for real this time.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import re

@contextmanager
def assign_match(regex, string):
    match = re.match(regex, string)
    if match:
        yield match.groups()

for i in range(3):
    with assign_match('(abc)(def)', 'abcdef') as a:
#    for a in assign_match('(abc)(def)', 'abcdef'):
        print(a)
        continue
    print(i)
```

Sorry for the post - I swear I was feeling really stuck before I posted. :-) Hopefully someone else will find this interesting!

Comment: you could write `for a, b in ...`

Comment: Explicit `raise StopIteration` is unnecessary. `if match: yield match.groups()` is sufficient.

Comment: just change the indentation level of `continue` to work on the correct loop. Your [`edit2` won't work](http://ideone.com/L5aoW)

Comment: Your final edit does not work. ``RuntimeError: generator didn't yield`` is raised whenever the regex fails.